# pls help me with this error imtrying to create adatabase in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans, connector

I get this erroer on mysql "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"Staff_information" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   ,"first_name" VARCHAR,"surname" ' at line 5"

CREATE TABLE "Staff_information" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   ,"first_name" VARCHAR,"surname" VARCHAR,
                                  "Dob" INTEGER DEFAULT (null) ,
                                  "Email" VARCHAR,"Telephone" VARCHAR,"Address" VARCHAR,"Department" VARCHAR,
                                  "Image" BLOB,"Gender" CHAR,
                                  "Salary" VARCHAR,"Address2" VARCHAR,"Apartment" VARCHAR,"Post_code" VARCHAR DEFAULT (null) ,
                                  "Designation" VARCHAR,"Status" VARCHAR,"Date_hired" VARCHAR,"job_title" VARCHAR)

Comment: How is this `java`-, `jdbc`-, `netbeans`- and `connector`-related? Also, please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is MySQL, the datatype you are using should be INT, not integer.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has a couple of issues.

- You should't use the `"`-Symbol in the create Table query
- The `DEFAULT(null)` you can omit, because null is already the set default
- You have to add the character amount to the `VARCHAR` and `CHAR` columns e.g. `VARCHAR(255)`

So your statement should be working looking like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Staff_information 
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(255), surname VARCHAR(255), Dob INTEGER, 
Email VARCHAR(255), Telephone VARCHAR(255), Address VARCHAR(255), Department VARCHAR, 
Image BLOB, Gender CHAR(50), Salary VARCHAR(255), Address2 VARCHAR(255), Apartment 
VARCHAR(255), Post_code VARCHAR(255), Designation VARCHAR(255), Status VARCHAR(255), 
Date_hired VARCHAR(255), job_title VARCHAR(255));
```